# Update SQL command is not updating SQL record using JSP

Tags: sql, jsp, sql-update

I am trying to update SQL table record but nothing changes done in SQL table. Whenever I do changes in input JSP page and do click on update button then record is not getting updated. I have **id** as a primary key in my table. Using **id** I am updating record.

**Here is update.jsp**

```html
<body>
<%
Connection con;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement stat = null;    
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");
%>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<%
stat = con.createStatement();
String id = request.getParameter("id");
String data = "select * from dmsfiles where id = '"+id+"'";
rs = stat.executeQuery(data);
while(rs.next()){
 %>    
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=rs.getString("id") %>"/>
<center>
<table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="5">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Update Record</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td><input type="text" required="" name="id1" value="<%=rs.getString("id")%>" readonly=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Z id</td>
<td>
<input type="text" required="" name="zid" value="<%=rs.getString("zid")%>"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" required="" name="firstname" value="<%=rs.getString("firstname")%>"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" required="" name="lastname" value="<%=rs.getString("lastname")%>"/>
</td>
</tr>

...

<tr>
<td><label class="hidden">Issuer</label></td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="issuer" class="hidden" value="<%=rs.getString("issuer")%>"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label class="hidden">Status</label></td>
<td>
<select name="status" class="hidden" id="wgtmsr">
<option value="<%=rs.getString("status")%>"><%=rs.getString("status")%></option>
<option value="Public">Reserved</option>
<option value="Team">Implemented</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<%  
}
%>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"/>Update</td>
<td><a href="home.jsp" class="btn btn-info">Back</a></td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
<%
    String id1 = request.getParameter("id");
    String a = request.getParameter("zid");
    String b = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String c = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String d = request.getParameter("mailid");
    
    ...
    
    String u = request.getParameter("issuer");
    String v = request.getParameter("status");
    if(a!=null && b!=null && c!=null && d!=null && e!=null && f!=null && g!=null && h!=null && i!=null && j!=null && k!=null && l!=null && m!=null && n!=null && o!=null && p!=null && q!=null && r!=null && s!=null && t!=null && u!=null && v!=null){
        String query = "update dmsfiles set id=?, zid=?, firstname=?, lastname=?, mailid=?, division=?, department=?, costcentercode=?, document_number=?, document_name=?, document_type=?, document_category=?, document_classification=?, authorised_by=?, fromdate=?, todate=?, document_level=?, document_general=?, serial_number=?, revision_number=?, issuer=?, status=? where id='"+id1+"'";
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, id1);
        stmt.setString(2, a);
        stmt.setString(3, b);
        stmt.setString(4, c);
        stmt.setString(5, d);
        
        ...
        
        stmt.setString(19, r);
        stmt.setString(20, s);
        stmt.setString(21, t);
        stmt.setString(22, u);
        stmt.setString(23, v);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
    }
%>
```

Comment: Debug your code: 1-st: Is IF-condition fulfilled (true)? Just do debugging output after `if(a!=null && b!=null && c!=null...`   2-nd: try to execute SQL-Query UPDATE dmsfiles .... on MySQL-Console. Make a debugging output of this query from your JSP-Code. 3-th: you don't check your MySQL-connection. Best practice is to check DB-connection before you proceed with SQL-queries.

Comment: I did debugging for `if` statement then I checked id is showing as `null`

Comment: Maybe instead of `rs.getString("id")` you should use `rs.getInt("id").toString()` ?  Make debugging output from every place ID could change.

Comment: I tried but id showing `null`

Comment: Maybe you should SELECT each SQL field explicitly: `select id, zid, firstname... from dmsfiles where id = ....`